# How to optimize partition strategy of Kafka topic for consumption with Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am very new to kafka and trying to write data into a topic and read from the same topic (We are acting as a source team to ingest data for now. Hence we are doing both operations of Write to Kafk topic for and consume from the same topic).
I wrote the below code on spark-shell to write data into a Kafka topic.

```
pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0,io.strimzi:kafka-oauth-client:0.5.0

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DecimalType, TimestampType, DateType
tn = "topic_name"
kafka_broker = "brokerurl:9500"
endpoint_uri = "endpoint_uri"
client_id = "clientid"
client_secret = "secret_key"
jaas_config = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required"
oauth_client = " oauth.client.id='{0}'".format(client_id)
oauth_secret = " oauth.client.secret='{0}'".format(client_secret)
oauth_token_endpoint_uri = " oauth.token.endpoint.uri='{0}'".format(endpoint_uri)
oauth_config = jaas_config + oauth_client + oauth_secret + oauth_token_endpoint_uri + " oauth.max.token.expiry.seconds='30000' ;"

df = spark.sql("select * from dbname.tablename where geography in ('ASIA', 'LATIN_AMERICA') and geo_year in (2020, 2021)").select(F.to_json(F.struct(F.col("*"))).alias("value"))


# WRITE TO TOPIC
df.write.format("kafka")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker)\
        .option("kafka.batch.size", 51200)\
        .option("retries", 3)\
        .option("kafka.max.request.size", 500000)\
        .option("kafka.max.block.ms", 120000)\
        .option("kafka.metadata.max.age.ms", 120000)\
        .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", 120000)\
        .option("kafka.linger.ms", 0)\
        .option("kafka.delivery.timeout.ms", 130000)\
        .option("acks", "1")\
        .option("kafka.compression.type", "snappy")\
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", oauth_config)\
        .option("kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class", "io.strimzi.kafka.oauth.client.JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler")\
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "OAUTHBEARER")\
        .option("topic", tn)\
        .save()
```

Later on I came to know that, a Kafka topic can contain data in partitions. So I deleted and recreated the same topic but this time with 3 partitions.

All of my spark experience is in batch processing and the concept of partitioning exists even there where we partition the data while reading a table or a file using

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('', '')
               ...
               ...
               .option('partitionColumn', 'partitionColumn_name')
               .load()
```

This partition column used in batch processing is typically a column with high cardinality & we can also specify number of partitions we want to split the data into using

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('', '')
               ...
               ...
               .option('partitionColumn', 'partitionColumn_name').option('numPartitions', INTEGER_VALUE_OF_PARTITIONS)
               .load()
```

I have seen custom partitioner classes in plain Kafka code but I am using spark-streaming and not even sure how can I integrate that.
My confusion with Kafka topic partitioning is with the below points:

1. How do I choose the number of partitions per topic ? I am
   implementing spark streaming with Kafka.
2. Is there a way I can manage partitioning data using Spark streaming
   ?
3. If not, is there a way I can ensure an even distribution of data in
   the partitions of the topic.

I have gone thru [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#locationstrategies) official documentation.

But couldn't find any information on partitioning strategies there.
Could anyone provide me some clarity on how to write data to particular partition of a topic or is it better to leave it to Kafka.

Edit 1:
I have just gone thru this [link](https://dattell.com/data-architecture-blog/kafka-optimization-how-many-partitions-are-needed/) and there is a formula mentioned to calculate the number of partitions need based on the throughput.
Is that an approach we can follow to determine number partitions per Topic ?

Any clarification is going to be of much  value to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a broad topic with questions that require some thorough answers. Anyway, most importantly:

- in general, Kafka scales with the number of partitions in a topic
- Spark scales with the number of worker nodes and available cores/slots
- each partition of the Kafka topic can only be consumed by a single Spark task (parallelsim then depends on the number of Spark wcores)
- if you have multiple Spark workers but only one Kafka topic partition, only one core can consume the data
- Likewise, if you have multiple Kafka topic partitions but only one worker node with a single core, the "parallelism" is 1
- remember that a formular usually represents a theory which for simplicity leaves out details. The formular you have cited is a good starting point but in the end it depends on your environment such as: requirements for latency or theoughput, network bandwith/traffic, available hardware, costs etc.
  That being said, only you can do testing for optimisations.

As a side note, when writing to Kafka from Spark Structured Streaming, if your Dataframe contains the column "partition" it will be used to send the record to the corresponding partition (starting from 0). You can also have the column "topic" in the dataframe which allows you to send the record to a certain topic.

Spark Structured Streaming will send each record individually to Kafka.