# Does Spark Structured Streaming producer using the Kafka default partitioner between Spark partitions or only within partition?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

If we have the records with the same key are in different **Spark partitions**, will the Spark Kafka writer send partition it correctly for **Kafka partitions** (using the default Kafka partitioner by key)?

For example, right before writing to Kafka we have the **Spark partitions** like this:

```
| key     | `Spark` partition |
| ------- | ----------------- |
| key1    | 1                 |
| key1    | 1                 |
| key1    | 2                 |
```

Will it be writer to Kafka correctly:

```
| key     | `Spark` partition | `Kafka` partition |
| ------- | ----------------- |-------------------| 
| key1    | 1                 | 1                 |
| key1    | 1                 | 1                 |
| key1    | 2                 | 1                 |
```

Which means, the Spark-Kafka writer repartitions data before using the `partition "local" producer`, or I must repartition it before to ensure it happens?

```
readyToSendToKafka
  .repartition("key")
```

Comment: `repartition` is only a Spark method. The built-in Kafka partitioner will still be called, regardless. Therefore, the Spark partitions shouldn't matter since the Murmur2 hash for the keys should be equal, and will be written to the same topic partition.

Comment: My question is if the Kafka partitioner is called over the whole dataframe, or only for the data (spark partitions) it gets.

Comment: It's applied over the whole dataframe, but foreach dataframe partition since that's what are actually iterated over when the Kafka producer's send method is invoked.

Comment: I don't fully get it. If it's actually applied inside a foreachPartition, it's not called over the whole dataframe and happens only per partition. If so, there is no guarantee same keys will be sent from the same producer over the entire dataframe, and therefore ordering can't be ensured.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the key, like so:

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(SomeCol AS STRING) as key", "CAST(someCol2 AS STRING) as value")
.writeStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
.option("topic", "sometopic")
.save()
```

then, as Kafka distributes messages based on their keys,  messages with same key will go to same Kafka Topic partition.

If no key set, then round robin applies. Nothing to do with dataframe partitioning as such.

**Update**

[How to optimize partition strategy of Kafka topic for consumption with Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099675/how-to-optimize-partition-strategy-of-kafka-topic-for-consumption-with-structure)

We learn that since some time...

> As a side note, when writing to Kafka from Spark
> Structured Streaming, if your Dataframe contains the column
> "partition" it will be used to send the record to the corresponding
> partition (starting from 0). You can also have the column "topic" in
> the dataframe which allows you to send the record to a certain topic.

Comment: Or an integer `partition` column can be manually added